# SP 2013/Designer 2013 - InfoPath Issue

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I am trying to rename the OOTB Collect Feedback Workflow Task form “Cancel” button to “Save for Later” using InfoPath. Upon renaming the button and clicking Quick Publish I am receiving a “The following URL is not valid: www.server.com” error (refer to screenshot).
I’ve done some investigating and multiple users on the msdn forums have mentioned adding HTTP Verbs have solved their issue. So I went ahead and added; PUT, PROPFIND, OPTIONS, HEADER, GET and DELETE (refer to screenshot) and it is still throwing me the invalid URL error!

Ive been pulling out my hair trying to figure out this issue. Any suggestions would help!

Cheers
[image]